# Is it possible to combine classes in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a en element `<div clas="foo bar foobar">[stuff]</div>` and I want to replace these three classes with one class (SuperFoo).

While I could find out how foo, bar and foobar are defined, and use each of those elements:

`.SuperFoo { color : red }` and so on,  is it possible to define SuperFoo in terms of foo, bar and foobar?

`.SuperFoo { foo bar foobar}`?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless you use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/features/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/guide)'s 'mixin' features, there's no real way in plain CSS to "inherit" other classes.

The best you can do is apply all three classes to your DOM element.

If your problem is that you have a ton of those classes already on a page and you want to add properties to all of them, you can do:

```
.foo, .bar, .foobar {
    color: red;
}
```

and that will apply color: red to any element that has .foo or .bar or .foobar.

Answer (score 9):

No. But you could use chained classes:

```css
.foo.bar.foobar {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo bar foobar">[red]</div>
```