# Assign Styles to a selector from another selector CSS

Tags: css

Is there a way to have a class or any selector with specific styles, and then share, import or assign those styles to a another selector. This is to avid creating multiple classes and not having to go back to the HTML code all the time to assign such classes.

For example:

```
.orangeText{
 color:orange
}

.strongtext{
 font-weight:900
}
```

a regular scenario would use those clases like this:

```
<div class="orangeText strongtext">My orange Strong Text</div>
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
.orangeText{
 color:orange
}

.strongtext{
 font-weight:900
}

.orangeStrongTitle{
  @.orangeText; /* Import styles from .orangeText*/
  @.strongtext; /* Import styles from .strongtext*/
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

ON HTML:

```
<div class="orangeStrongTitle">My orange Strong Text</div>
```

> PLEASE NOTE THAT @.orangeText IS MY INVENTION TO GIVE AN EXAMPLE OF WHAT I WANT, I DON'T KNOW IF SUCH THING EXISTS, I WAS INSPIRED ON @import

Is this possible?

Comment: Use LESS. With that you can literally just put `.orangeText; .strongtext; text-decoration: underline;` and it'll compile to the appropriate CSS. Takes some setup but it does make things a lot easier (especially the nesting feature).

Comment: Also u can use SASS

Comment: Thanks @NiettheDarkAbsol, I am looking for a vanilla solution, I don't have the option right now of installing or using third party libraries, but please add your solution as answer with a working example and I will definitely up-vote your answer.

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzMiśkiewicz, same thing please add a working example as an answer and I will up-vote it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With traditional CSS it seem's that you can't.

See this topic : [Is it possible to combine classes in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038035/is-it-possible-to-combine-classes-in-css)

> Unless you use LESS or SASS's 'mixin' features, there's no real way in
>   plain CSS to "inherit" other classes.     The best you can do is apply
>   all three classes to your DOM  element. If your problem is that you
>   have a ton of those classes already on a page and  you want to add
>   properties to all of them, you can do:
>
> ```
> .foo, .bar, .foobar {
>     color: red;
> }
> ```
>
> and that will apply color: red to any element that has .foo or .bar or
>   .foobar.

**EDIT**

Since you're asking for an exemple, here is how the mixin feature of SASS works :

```
@mixin mixin-name {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  @include mixin-name;
}
```

Having this will compile into this :

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```