# Can you reference a CSS class within another CSS class

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, scss-mixins

Everything that I have researched comes up with ways to nest CSS. That's not what I am trying to do.

**UPDATE:** The question that was associated with mine which caused it to close does not have an answer that helps. Most answers are years old. One answer mentions using LESS, so I would ask how that can work with the Rails 7 asset pipeline.

**What I am trying to accomplish**

I am trying to reference a CSS class within another CSS class to limit replication. Much like a variable is used.

**Example**

I am using Bootstrap for my design foundation. Within the footer section, there are columns that each have the following classes specified:

`col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-5 mb-lg-0`

I'd like to make a class `footer-section` and reference those classes above. That way if I should want to change how the sections are shown, I don't have to go through each to update, just update the CSS class.

**Example Bootstrap Code**

```
.col-lg-3 {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 25%;
}
.col-md-6 {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}
.mb-5 {
  margin-bottom: 3rem !important;
}
.mb-lg-0 {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

What I'd like my `custom-footer.scss` to look like:

```
footer {
    .footer-section {
        .col-lg-3, .col-md-6, .mb-5, .mb-lg-0
    }
  
    /* Other Code */
}
```

HTML

```
<footer>
     <div class="footer-section">
         ... Section content
     </div>
     <div class="footer-section">
         ... Section content
     </div>
     <div class="footer-section">
         ... Section content
     </div>
</footer>
```

**In practice**

With the above code it would then be easy to change all sections within the footer by just updating the CSS `footer .footer-section {}` declaration

**My Development Environment**

I am using Ruby on Rails for Development and my Asset Pipeline looks like this:

```
app/assets/stylesheets--
                        |
                        pages--
                        |      |
                        |      legal_styles.scss
                        |
                         _variables.css
                         application.css
                         changed_bootstrap.scss
                         custom_text_styles.scss
                         custom.scss
                         footer_styles.scss

vendor/assets/stylesheets--
                           |
                            animate.min.css
                            bootstrap.min.css
                            bootstrap.min.css.map
```

`application.css Code`

```
/* application.css file
 
 *= require _variables
 
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require animate.min
 *= require font-awesome
 
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

**UPDATE:** So, per a comment and suggested answer, I tried this in my `footer_styles.scss` file:

```
.footer-section {
        @extend .col-lg-3;
        @extend .col-md-6;
        @extend .mb-5;
        @extend .mb-lg-0;
}
```

But, I get a compile error that the 'target selector was not found.' I call for the `bootstrap.min.css` to be called before the `footer_styles.scss` is called. So, the selector should be visible within the compiled `application.css` file before it is `@extended`. So, I am not sure what is going on there or if I am doing something wrong.

**Justification**

I know that I could just copy the Bootstrap code for each class over to the `.section` area, but that would be a duplication of code.

I know that the footer section is centralized and only has a few areas, so maintenance/updates would be rather easy; but, I'd like to utilize this type of technique in other areas of my site. I am seeing that I utilize the Bootstrap classes often together throughout my site and instead of updating each declaration on each page, it would be easy to just change the CSS code.

**Question**

Is it possible to 'reference', not nest, CSS classes within another CSS class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to combine classes in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038035/is-it-possible-to-combine-classes-in-css)

Comment: Scss mixins most likely...

Comment: Have you heard of CSS variables?

Comment: Also, you have tagged scss-mixins. Are you asking how to do this in CSS, or in SCSS?

Comment: I am asking about either CSS or SCSS. I am using Ruby on Rails for development and my stylesheets have book CSS and SCSS files.

Comment: @Jake It looks like that site doesn't help and the answers are older than 8 years; so, I'm not sure they'd help. I am updating my question with more information.

Comment: One big problem here is  that you're using the sprockets directive `*= require_tree .` which doesn't play nice with sass at all. What happens is that each file will be fed by sprockets to the compiler individually so any variables, functions etc that are defined in another file will not be accessable. You want to use the sass compiler instead to stiich the files together. If you're still on libsass (the Sass-c) gem that means using the `@include` directive.

Comment: However the modern way is to use the [SASS module system `@use`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use). This is only available on Dart-Sass and fixes a lot of the problems with @include (which is a horrible kludge). Libsass hasn't gotten any new features since 2018 and was deprechiated in 2020.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend

```css
.error:hover {
  background-color: #fee;
}

.error--serious {
  @extend .error;
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

Comment: This would work, if the classes were all in one file, but they are not. During launch the .SCSS and .CSS files are all compiled into one `application.css` file, but when it gets to the `@extend` it errors as the class is unable to be found. I would have to add the `footer-section` class to the `bootstrap.min.css` file directly to get it to work. I am trying to avoid that to future proof against Bootstrap updates.

Comment: Another problem here is that this just removes the duplication before compilation. Overusing `@extend` can lead to very heavy style sheets.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues/ideas here to tackle.

### Don't use Sprockets directives

`#= require` and `#= require_tree` are extremely primitive and read each file and then pass them into the compiler one by one. The result is then concatenated and fed into any postprocessors. This does not work well with Sass or any other kind of precompiler where you can use variables or functions defined in another file.

So you want to change your assets manifest into a SCSS file and use let the SASS compiler do the work.

With the deprechiated LibSass sass compiler you're stuck with `@includes`:

```sass
// application.scss
@include 'variables';
@include 'changed_bootstrap';
@include 'custom_text_styles';
@include 'custom';
@include 'footer_styles';
```

Note that the files you're including should have their names prefixed with an underscore as they are not intended to compile into individual files.

However the modern way going forward is to use Dart-Sass and SASS modules:

```sass
// style.scss
@use 'variables';
@use 'changed_bootstrap';
```

This fixes a lot of the headaches involved with `@includes` which is actually a CSS feature that the SASS compiler clobbers.

### Inheritance in CSS

You have to remember that CSS was designed as a simple declaritive language. It does not have inheritance in the sense that you can inherit from another rule.

CSS did get [custom properties (variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) relatively recently which lets you resuse values at least.

### Copy-pasting SASS style

Sass has `@extend` which basically just copies all the attributes of one CSS rule to another:

```
.foo {
  color: "red";
}

.bar {
  @extend .foo;
  display: block;
}
```

Which compiles down into:

```
.foo {
  color: "red";
}

.bar {
  color: :red;
  display: block;
}
```

However the rule you're defining must be in a file previously loaded by the SASS compiler. While SASS can load plain CSS files as SASS is a superset I can't guarentee that what you're doing there will actually work.

While Bootstrap was in the past ported to Sass from Less so that your could reuse parts of it remember that Bootstrap is 11 years old and has aged like milk. If you want to use it just live with the fact that your HTML is going to be a soup of purely presentational classes.